# Java variable may not have been initialized

Tags: java, initialization

I'm working on Project Euler [Problem 9](https://projecteuler.net/problem=9), which states:

A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, a < b < c, for which,

```
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
```

For example, 3^2 + 4^2 = 9 + 16 = 25 = 52.

There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which a + b + c = 1000.
Find the product abc.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
class Project_euler9 {

    public static boolean determineIfPythagoreanTriple(int a, int b, int c) {
        return (a * a + b * b == c * c);
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean answerFound = false;
        int a, b, c;
        while (!answerFound) {
            for (a = 1; a <= 1000; a++) {
                for (b = a + 1; b <= 1000; b++) {
                    c = 1000 - a - b;
                    answerFound = determineIfPythagoreanTriple(a, b, c);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("(" + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ")");
    }
}
```

When I run my code, I get this error:

```
Project_euler9.java:32: error: variable a might not have been initialized
        System.out.println("The Pythagorean triplet we're looking for is (" + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ")");
```

Note: I get this for each of my variables (a, b, and c) just with different line numbers.

I thought that when I declared a, b, and c as integers, the default value was 0 if left unassigned.

Even if this weren't the case, it looks to me like they all *do* get assigned, so I'm a bit confused about the error.

Why is this happening?

Comment: In addition to what Oscar wrote, there's no point to have the while loop cause you're not checking it (`answerFound`) until the for-loops are done...

Answer (score 7):

Instance variables (in your case, they would be *integers*) are assigned to `0` be default. Local variables **not**. *[(From Java Docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)*

If the loop is not entered, then your variables won't be initialized, that's the reason of the error.

What you can do is **initialize them when declaring**:

```
int a=0, b=0, c=0;
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is this line:

```
System.out.println("(" + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ")");
```

which is after the `while (!answerFound) {...}` loop. The compiler thinks that there may be a case where one or more of the variables `a`, `b` or `c` isn't initialised.

Use this line:

```
int a=0, b=0, c=0;
```

when declaring the variables, so that they are initialised when declared, and the error should go away.

Answer (score 3):

Do this, at the beginning of the method after the local variables are declared:

```
a = b = c = 0;
```

The error is basically stating that Java can't be sure that the variables have a value assigned when they reach the `System.out.println()`. Remember: in Java only attributes have default values, all local variables must be explicitly initialized at some point.

Answer (score 3):

You're right and wrong in your thinking:

Where you're right:

- Yes, uninitialized variables may be assigned a value by the compiler, but a) it is considered bad style, b) You shouldn't depend on it, c) That does not apply to local variables (as declared in a method)

Where you are wrong:

- Local variables are not assigned a default value, only instance variables.

For reference, take a look at [The docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> Default Values
>
> It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared.
>   **Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a
>   reasonable default by the compiler.** Generally speaking, this default
>   will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such
>   default values, however, is generally considered bad programming
>   style.
>
> The following chart summarizes the default values for the above data
>   types.
>
> Data Type Default Value (for fields) 
>   byte  0 
>   short 0  
>   int   0  
>   long  0L 
>   float 0.0f  
>   double    0.0d  
> char '\u0000'  
> String (or any object)   null 
>   boolean   false
>
> **Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a
>   default value to an uninitialized local variable.** If you cannot
>   initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to
>   assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an
>   uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `local variables` in a method, you have to assign them values before use them.

Answer (score 1):

The Java compiler has to be convinced that when we get to the line `HERE`, it can prove that `a`, `b`, and `c` have been set to something:

```
   boolean answerFound = false;
   int a, b, c;
   while (!answerFound) {
       for (a = 1; a <= 1000; a++) {
           for (b = a + 1; b <= 1000; b++) {
               c = 1000 - a - b;
               answerFound = determineIfPythagoreanTriple(a, b, c);
           }
       }
   }
   // HERE
```

From the compiler's point of view, if the loop is executed zero times, then it will get to `HERE` without the variables being initialized; therefore, you can't use them.  *We* know that this is impossible, because we know that `answerFound` is initialized to `false` and therefore the loop will be executed at least once, and also that each `for` loop will be executed at least once.  But the language has to have consistent rules to determine which programs are legal and which ones aren't; in order to keep things from being overly complex, the compiler isn't required to make the kinds of deductions that would be necessary to prove that `a`, `b`, and `c` are always initialized.  I haven't looked at the actual "definite assignment" rules in detail, but I think they're already fairly complex.

So even though you know that the variables will be initialized, you can't convince the compiler of that.  So just initialize them when they're declared.

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
```

By the way, since the `while` is **outside** the `for` loops, this code will not exit right away when `answerFound` becomes `true`.  It still executes the `for` loops until they're done, and only then does it test to see whether to leave the `while` loop.  You'll need to solve that.

P.S. If you want to cheat, note that every Pythagorean triple has the form *a = m<sup>2</sup> - n<sup>2</sup>*, *b = 2mn*, *c = m<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>2</sup>*, for some *m* and *n*.  You could actually get the answer without a computer, using algebra.  But go ahead and finish the program you started--it's great practice.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out your variables `a, b, c` may not have been initialized by the time you get to `System.out.println`. There are several ways to avoid this.

Initialize variables **explicitly**, so:

```
int a = 0;
```

Use a **do...while** loop, which ensures your loop is run at least once, so:

```
do {
    [...]
} while (!answerFound);
```

Use **loop-scoped** variables, which avoid local-scoped variables hanging around, so:

```
for (int a = 1; a <= 1000; a++) {
    [...]
}
```